# How to paste the whole range from Excel to Lotus as bitmap?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a macro that works out quite well. I'm able to copy and paste given range (to be precise a pivot table) as bitmap but the problem is that not the whole are is copied, only a part of a table.

Here is the code, what's wrong with pasting? Why can't I copy the whole table?

```
Public Sub Lotus_Mail()

Dim NSession As Object
Dim NUIWorkSpace As Object
Dim NDatabase As Object
Dim NDoc As Object
Dim NUIdoc As Object
Dim Subject As String
Dim SendTo As String, CopyTo As String
Dim pivots As Range
Dim Month As String
Dim text1 As Range
Dim text2 As Range
Dim i As Integer


Dim arrHUBs(1 To 8) As String

arrHUBs(1) = "a"
arrHUBs(2) = "b"
arrHUBs(3) = "c"
arrHUBs(4) = "d"
arrHUBs(5) = "e"
arrHUBs(6) = "f"
arrHUBs(7) = "g"
arrHUBs(8) = "h"

Week = DatePart("ww", Date, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
Month = MonthName(DatePart("m", Date), False)

On Error Resume Next

For x = 1 To 8

SendTo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(arrHUBs(x),      Sheets("Mail").Range("A2:C9"), 2, 0)
CopyTo = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(arrHUBs(x), Sheets("Mail").Range("A2:C9"), 3, 0)
Subject = "Summary " & arrHUBs(x) & " - " & Month & ": week " & Week

'area to select (pivot table)
rows = Sheets("sheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 21).End(xlUp).Row
columns = Sheets("sheet").Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set pivots = Sheets("sheet").Range(Cells(4, 19), Cells(wiersz, kolumna))
'Set pivots = Sheets("sheet").PivotTables("Pivot1")  ???this line doesn't work, any other way to select pivot and paste to Lotus?

Set text1 = Sheets("Mail").Range("A12")
Set text2 = Sheets("Mail").Range("A13")

'Lotus step by step
Set NSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession") 
Set NUIWorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Set NDatabase = NSession.GetDatabase("", "")
If Not NDatabase.IsOpen Then NDatabase.OPENMAIL

'creating mail
Set NDoc = NDatabase.CreateDocument

    With NDoc
    .SendTo = SendTo
    .CopyTo = CopyTo
    .Subject = Subject

    'Email body text, including a placeholder which will be replaced by Excel table

    .body = text1 & vbLf & vbLf & _
        "{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}" & vbLf

    .Save True, False
End With

'Edit the new document using Notes UI to copy and paste pivot table into it

Set NUIdoc = NUIWorkSpace.EDITDocument(True, NDoc)

With NUIdoc
    Sheets("sheet").Select

    'Find the placeholder in the Body item 

    .GotoField ("Body")        
    .FINDSTRING "{IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER}"
    '.DESELECTALL 'Uncomment to leave the placeholder in place (cells are inserted immediately before it)

    'Copy pivot table (being a range) as a bitmap to the clipboard and paste into the email

    pivots.CopyPicture xlBitmap
    .Paste 'maybe any paste special option exists?
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '.Send
    '.Close
End With

Set NSession = Nothing

Next x
End Sub
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: For starters, get rid of `On Error Resume Next`. That's a handy way to not have an ugly error message pop up, but it's also a _really_ handy way to have all your errors swept under the carpet leaving you stumped as to why your code isn't working. There are very, _very_ few places where `OERN` is useful when wrapping 1 or 2 lines of code. This isn't one of those cases. Odds are, that `OERN` is hiding the error message that would tell you _exactly_ what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Change `Set pivots = Sheets("sheet").Range(Cells(4, 19), Cells(wiersz, kolumna))` to `Set pivots = Sheets("sheet").Range(Sheets("sheet").Cells(4, 19), Sheets("sheet").Cells(wiersz, kolumna))` Next check the value of `wiersz` and `kolumna` and finally, add `DoEvents` after `pivots.CopyPicture xlBitmap`.

Comment: Thank you guys, but changing pivots as @SiddharthRout said changes nothing, still can't paste the whole table. Where is the problem? Variables **wiersz** and **kolumna** return proper values and all shoud work, I checked those variables. Really, don't know what is wrong

Comment: What if you do just `pivots.Copy`?

Comment: Still nothing. Are you familiar with any other way to copy paste pivot tables into Lotus Body?